# Consuming RESTful WCF Services using Java

Tags: c#, java, web-services, wcf, rest

There are similar questions but they seem to be pretty outdated; and hoping there might be a standard solution to this now.

Is there a standard library/framework that Java clients can use to consume .NET WCF services simply without any hassle setting up WSDL files; serializing/deserializing/parsing JSON files, or any of that?

How reliable would this be? I know I would have to ensure to keep consistent/similar data types between the 2 languages; but is there anything else that one might have to look out for when trying to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The java standard regarding Web services and RESTful are JAX-WS and JAX-RS in order. You can use any library that supports the above standards regardless of the server implementation technology.

Apache CXF, Jersey are few of the libraries that supports the above standards.

Apache CXF has wsdl2java tool which generates client for you. Netbeans, eclipse like IDEs have some Web service wizards which may create you the client in few clicks.